# Aspects of **have** in "You have me all confused!"

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, object-complements

I am a speaker of American English, mid-Atlantic dialect.  I was thinking of scenarios like the following:

> Yesterday, you said to do it *this* way, and this morning you said to do it *that* way, and now you're saying to do it yet another way. *You have me all confused!*

**have** there means something like "have made me, i.e. have caused me to become".

I would never say this:

> *Stop the splashing, you have my book all wet.

though I might well say this:

> Stop kicking the table leg! You have my *jenga* tower all discombobulated.

What's the difference between **wet** on the one hand and **confused**, and **discombobulated** on the other, that makes **You have my book all wet** a non-starter?

Comment: It's just a foible of yours that you find the *jenga tower all discombobulated* example more idiomatic than the *book all wet* one. Personally, I would never say *either* of them, and even *You have me all confused* sounds a bit "literary" (but I'm fine with ***You've got** me all confused!, You've got my book all wet!* etc.).

Comment: I can assure you, "You have me all confused!" is down-home American English with nothing literary about it.

Comment: ...and according to you, *You have my jenga tower all discombobulated* is equally "down-home American English", but for some reason, *You have my book all wet* isn't.

Comment: Not just according to me. I've asked other local speakers. All find *You have my book all wet* to be off, and some even said the **discombobulated** sentence sounds off. But there's general agreement on *You have me all confused" as being idiomatic.

Comment: @Tim If you insist on hiring a brass band to play at your party, you'll *have the neighbours complaining*.

Comment: @WS2:  But I won't *Have the neighbors angry* though  I might *Have the neighbors angry with me.*

Comment: @WS2 I agree with **complaining**, BTW. That would be idiomatic for me and those I've asked.

Answer (score 1):

**It is OED sense V 28 b of the verb *have*. They explain it as follows:**

> V.28.b. Old English– With complement. To bring into the specified
> state or condition, esp. deliberately; to cause to become; to make,
> render; e.g. she had them in tears. Cf. get v. III.26a.i. as luck
> would have it and variants: see Phrases P.1c.

The sense of the verb has been around for a long time. indeed there are examples from Old English:

> Gyf þu lædde þinne sunu to sancte Petres ciricean to Alexandre ðam
> papan, þonne hæfdest þu hine gesundne. Old English Martyrology (Julius
> MS.)

Some of the more recent examples are as follows:

> 1933 Little Robert Lynen..had he been properly directed would have us
> all in tears. Punch 6 December 638/2Citation details
>
> 1973 Before they'd done the Uey, he'd brushed his hair back, lit a
> Rothman's and had the window down. F. Moorhouse, Australian Stories
> 58Citation details
>
> 2007 Cydney had me so angry that I didn't feel like working at all. B.
> Hampton, Two Wrongs don't make it Right 63

Comment: Yes, I agree with the meaning, and stated it in the question. But my question is about certain complements being idiomatic and others sounding off.

Comment: @Tim But "You will have my book all wet" sounds fine to me. I think it is just that some forms are used more than others - really just a case of everyday usage.

Comment: Does it sound ok to you without **will**?

Comment: @Tim Nothing especially wrong with it idiomatically, but perhaps not something I would expect to hear used very much. It is far more likely someone would say "You've made my book all wet." That form would also be more common for the future case as well - "You'll make my book all wet".

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly extrapolation from a pattern (I don't have any source to back this up), **but**:

Adjectives which sound right as complements to **to have**, in the construction

> [Subject] **has/have** [Object] [Adjective]

seem to be those referring to **states of mind**.

In the case of your first example, "You have me all confused," *confused* clearly refers to a person's state of mind.

In your other example where *have* fits, "You have my Jenga tower all discombobulated," the word "discombobulated" *would normally* refer to a person's state of mind. Here, it's being used *metaphorically* to describe an inanimate object being in a state of disarray.

Contrast this with the situations where *have* **doesn't** fit: in "You [have?] my book all wet," *wet* doesn't describe a state of mind *at all*, not even metaphorically.

---

The one example you gave that doesn't really fit this pattern is "[Have?] the neighbors angry." *Angry* **is** a state of mind, but yet *have* still sounds wrong here. I believe the reason for this is that the word "angry" is so often used as a complement of **to make** (as in "You **made** the neighbors **angry**") that *have* sounds out of place due to being unexpected. It's jarring when a "stock phrase" isn't used as-is.

---

More examples of "states of mind" used with "to have":

> The joke had the audience in tears of laughter

> You had me worried there...

> They had themselves worked up over nothing.

Comment: State-of-mind adjectives occurred to me as a possible explanation, but I had to reject it, since this sounds idiomatic: *Why did you rearrange the pictures on the wall? You have them all crookéd.*

Comment: @Tim Nice catch, that does break the pattern

Comment: Not to mention the use of the present-tense **have** to insist that the picture-hanging perp *own* the crookedness :-)

Comment: @Tim I wonder if your question will end up being migrated to EL&U, as it's surprisingly difficult to answer!